# how to access this data in my activity?

Tags: java, android

```
public Bundle getCaseInfo(String param) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_SLECTED_TEETH) == 0) {
        b.putStringArrayList(param,mCaseInfo.teeth);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_PATIENT_TYPE) == 0) {
        b.putString(param, mCaseInfo.patient_type);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_PAIN_LEVEL) == 0) {
        b.putString(param, mCaseInfo.pain);
    } elseif(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_TIME_LEVEL) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.time);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_SWELLING_LEVEL) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.swelling);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_SENSITIVITY) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.sensitivity);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_ADVANCED_OPTION) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.advancedoption);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_OTHER_SYMPTOMS) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.othersymptoms);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_INSURANCE) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.insurance);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_FULL_NAME) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.fullname);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_TELEPHONE) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.telephone);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_AGE) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.age);
    } else if(param.compareTo(Constants.CASE_INFO_GENDER) == 0) {
        b.putString(param,mCaseInfo.gender);
    }
    return b;
}
```

How to get this details in my activity?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: i want to retrive this data in another activity

Comment: You can use the `putExtras()`-method to add your Bundle to the calling intent. Then, in the called Activity, you can access the data there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this :

```
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivityToBeCalled.class);
    Bundle mBundle = getCaseInfo("your_Param");//call your function to get bundle values
    mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
    startActivity(mIntent);//call second activity
```

Then, in the launched SecondActivityToBeCalled, you would read them via:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```

Comment: suppose i want to get only Constants.CASE_INFO_SLECTED_TEETH ,so in getcaseinfo what i have to pass as getCaseInfo(Constants.CASE_INFO_SLECTED_TEETH) or getCaseInfo(param)

Comment: i am confused, what you are asking for.  getCaseInfo(Constants.CASE_INFO_SLECTED_TEETH) or getCaseInfo(param) will be same if you do String param = Constants.CASE_INFO_SLECTED_TEETH;

Comment: I think your question is on reading the bundleValues for String ArrayList. If so, use --> getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(key);

Comment: getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(key),in place of key what i have to use,getCaseInfo("your_Param") in place of your_Param  what i have to use